# How do I configure multiple hard disks for a dolphindb data node

Tags: database, bigdata, dolphindb

Because the storage capacity of a hard disk is limited, I want to configure multiple storage hard disks for my dolphindb data node. How should I configure them?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the parameter `volumes` for a data node. If you would like to configure multiple disks, just put the paths there separated by comma.

```
volumes=/hdd/disk1,/hdd/disk2
```